# How to push the filtered data into data flow task in SSIS?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I need to push the filtered data into data flow task...
In the control flow task I have 2 'execute SQL task' and one Data flow task connected one after the other. HOW can I use the output result set of the Execute sql taks into the data flow ?
The two 'execute sql task' performs filter operations and is running fine while debugging.

Inside the datflow task I use a source OLEDB ? What shall I use as a source to get the filtered output data from SQL task in Control Flow...

Comment: I need to get the recent data into the data flow task.. How could this be achieved... I'm not sure whether if we connect the sql task with the data flow will implicitly allow the filtered data into the data flow,, can someone guide me on this please...

Answer (score 1):

Adding to this, since you have two EST (Execute SQL Task) which generate a filtered data set which needs to be passed to a DFT (Data Flow Task), you can use a variable substitution method.

Here, you can replace direct SQL with a variable and, create a dynamic SQL using Script task and assign final SQL to the SSIS variable. Now in DFT, use SQL with variable option in your OLEDB Source, this will allow you to get rid of 2 EST's with a single variable which has T-SQL statements

Answer (score 0):

The output data of the Execute SQL Task must be written into the some storage OR in object type variable which can be used as a source in your data flow task.

You can also filter the data in source of the data flow task.

You can store the output of execute SQL task to #Temp table (other properties like delay validation, remainSameConnetion will be required to be set TRUE) OR Permanent table and access that from data flow.